# Detect in TWA App / Playstore that app is compatible or not

Tags: java, android-studio, trusted-web-activity

I asked already here: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa/issues/31 but still dont get a usefull reply. So... Someone have any idea how i can check if a TWA App is compatible with a users device or not? I get alot requests from users they download my [TWA](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devMonkeys.expenser) and tell me that it is not working for them. (They see only a white screen)

Comment: Can you provide more details on devices / browsers where the issue is happening? The code that checks for TWA availability on the device is part of the Support Library, and can be found here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/blob/master/customtabs/src/android/support/customtabs/trusted/TwaProviderPicker.java#L102-L171

Comment: It have nothing to do with Chrome i think. svgomg-twa is a in Java written App that gets compiled to an .apk file. When i place this .apk file in playstore, i just want that people can see the .apk only if they have minimum chrome 75+ installed. Otherwhise the store entry (.apk file) have to be hidden for the users. something like the `minSdkVersion 16` in `app/build.gradle` when people with SdkVersion under 16 search for the app in the playstore they simple will not find the App. This is what i want.

Comment: Would be helpful if there is a setting named `minChromeVersion`.